# Extracting URL from active Window (if Chrome or IE is opened ) through JNA

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I need your help to extract the Active Window URL details.

I got few links to get Active Window and window title

```
char[] buffer = new char[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH * 2];
HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();
User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowText(hwnd, buffer, MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
System.out.println("Active window title: " + Native.toString(buffer));
```

If active window is Chrome How do I get what is URL currently being browsed?

Comment: You can use UIAutomation. It is the value of "Address and search bar" edit control. Quick test using [Inspect tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects).

Comment: IE hands you the information if you ask for it: [A big little program: Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows, part 1: Enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130610-00/?p=4133).

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to right path .. I m looking for samples in Java code ( JNA) any links would be helpful